# DISC correlation with Big Five personality

Tags: personality, test, big-five

Apparently DISC (dominance, inducement, submission, and compliance) is a [kind of personality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DISC_assessment).

When/where is it used and how does it correlate with Big Five?

Answer (score 5):

According to [Jones and Hartley (2013)](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1054970.pdf), it's a test seldom mentioned in textbooks, but "used extensively in industry", more precisely in business organizations. Thee same paper also provides cross-correlation with Big Five factors:

[image]

Since the names in the left column of this table are a bit unusual ("left factors"), they are (in this order)

- the opposite of Extraversion
- the opposite of Openness
- the opposite of Agreeableness
- Conscienscouness (not negated)
- the opposite of Neuroticism

Also the Wikipedia descriptions of "DISC" factors don't quite agree with Jones and Hartley, which give them as

- Drive/Dominance (D) – task-oriented, fast-mover, bottom-line-oriented
- Influence (I) – people-oriented, energetic, desire popularity and praise
- Steadiness (S) – very people and family-oriented, motivated by loyalty and security, slower-moving
- Compliance/Conscientiousness (C) – task and detail-oriented, wants all information, slower-moving

The correlations are pretty weak, but some "conclusions" are amusing: to be "stable" (i.e. non-neurotic in Big Five terms) one needs to be steady/submissive (and not dominant/driven) and the opposite goes for "tough-minded", or otherwise put, being agreeable looks (again) like being submissive/steady and not dominant. Being "closed minded" is correlated with being steady/submissive and not being good at influencing/inducing other people. And an introvert is "compliant" (??) and again not good at influencing other people. These "conclusions" don't make a lot of sense to me, except maybe the last one...